# Getting to about.config in firefox

Tags: firefox

I'm using the Firefox browser, and I'm trying to change the browser configuration. I know that I do that via **about.config**.  But I can't get there; Firefox seems to insist on doing a *search* for **about.config** instead. How can I get to **about.config**? must be missing something simple.

---

Sorry, I kept typing about.config rather than about:config.

Answer (score 6):

It's **about:config**, not **about.config** (colon, not dot). `about:` is treated as protocol prefix.

Comment: You should post this as an answer

Comment: This **is** an answer, what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry - I thought it was posted as a comment!  I did upvote it though.